# Display grid of button with animation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, button, grid

currently i am trying to create a grid of button in my iPhone screen & it is happening perfectly but all these buttons are creating instantly.
Now what i want, when these button displayed on screen , it should be created orderly manner one after another in smooth animation.

How to achieve this ?

```
#define WIDTH 70
#define HEIGHT 70
#define PADDING 3
#define NUMBEROFBUTTONSINAROW 3
#define X 100
#define Y 100
#define TOTALBUTTONS 6

-(void)createButton{

    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for(int i=0 ; i<TOTALBUTTONS;i++)
    {
        UIButton *btnClick = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [btnClick setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"0.jpg"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btnClick setFrame:CGRectMake(X+((WIDTH + PADDING) * (i%NUMBEROFBUTTONSINAROW)), Y + (HEIGHT + PADDING)*(i/NUMBEROFBUTTONSINAROW), WIDTH, HEIGHT)];
        [btnClick addTarget:self action:@selector(btnTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        btnClick.tag=i + 1;

        [array addObject:btnClick];
        [self.view addSubview:btnClick];

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, inside your for loop button creation add this line:

```
[btnClick setAlpha:0.0];
```

than create a class variable (let's call it animationCounter) and set it to 0 and also set the buttons array (currently called "array") as a class varibale. After that we can create the following method:

```
-(void)animateButtons
{
   if (animationCounter < 10) {
      [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                 animations:^{
                     ((UIButton *)[self.array objectAtIndex:animationCounter]).alpha = 1.0;
                 } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     animationCounter++;
                     [self animateButtons];
                 }];
   }
}
```

Comment: Please try now, I forgot to add the animationCounter++ in the completion part